# How exactly do I do this

Tags: lua

In lua --
Im making a game where you need to sell items.
I have two tables. One for items,
and one for item costs.

```
itemcosts = {
  "Chewed Gum" == 5,
  "Leaf" == 2,
  "Lint" == 5,
  "Moldy bread crumbs" == 10
}
items = {"Leaf"}
```

How would I like specify the price? Like I tried

```
price = itemcosts[items[1]]
```

but It didn't work.
Any help?

Comment: Try `for k,v in pairs(itemcosts) do print(k,v) end` to understand the contents of that table.

Comment: It's not clear what "typo" it was closed for; I voted to close due to lack of debugging info, i.e. "it didn't work" as a problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your `itemcosts` table like this:

```
itemcosts = {
  ["Chewed Gum"] = 5,
  Leaf = 2,
  Lint = 5,
  ["Moldy bread crumbs"] = 10
}
```

When you want to use a table key that's a valid name in Lua, you don't need quotes or anything around it; just use it directly. When it's not a valid name, such as if it has spaces in it in your case, or even if it weren't a string at all, then you need square brackets around it. Also, remember that `==` is for comparison and `=` is for assignment.

Comment: It still didn't fix it.

Comment: @xcr What output are you getting exactly, once you make that change?

Comment: Better use `["Leaf"]` etc for consistency.

Comment: The output is the same.
I asked on how to get the item name for the item cost..

Comment: @xcr: You never said what the output was to begin with. Please edit that into the question.